# Can`t overload the operator << for a my own class

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to reduce code redundancy using the overload of an output operator to a stream instead of print functions.

```
//***.h
class MainWind : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWind(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWind();
    MainWind *operator<<(const QString &str);
private:
    Ui::MainWind *ui;
};

//***.cpp
MainWind *MainWind::operator<<(const QString &str)
{
    ui->serverConsole->insertPlainText(str);
    return this;
}
```

At this moment everything compiles successfully.

But when I try to use:

```
//other.cpp
MainWind *mainWind  = new MainWind;
mainWind << QString("str");
```

I got this error:

> ServerSocket.cpp:39: error: invalid operands to binary expression
>   ('MainWind *' and 'QString')
>   qstring.h:1410: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from >'MainWind *' to 'QDataStream &' for 1st argument
>
> ...
>
> And there are a lot of candidates for this position)

Or

```
//other.cpp
MainWind *mainWind  = new MainWind;
mainWind <<"str";
```

I got this error:

> ServerSocket.cpp:39: error: invalid operands to binary expression
>   ('MainWind *' and 'const char [4]') ServerSocket.cpp:39: error:
>   invalid operands of types 'MainWind*' and 'const char [4]' to binary
>   'operator<<'
>            CurrentSession::inst().mainWind() << "str";
>
> ```
>                                                   ^
> ```

What could be the problem?

ADDITION TO THIS QUESTION:

Attempt to use:

```
//*.h
friend MainWind *operator<<(MainWind *out,QString &str);

//***.cpp
MainWind * operator<<(MainWind *out, QString &str)
{
    out->ui->serverConsole->insertPlainText(str);
    return out;
}
```

Compilation of previous code is successful.

According to the idea, if the first operand could not be a pointer, this code would not compile...

But when using this:

```
//other.cpp
MainWind *mW = new MainWind;
mW << "str";
```

Compilation go to error:

> ServerSocket.cpp:37: error: invalid operands of types 'MainWind*' and 'const char [4]' to binary 'operator<<'
>                   mW << "str";
>
> ```
>                 ^
> ```

Comment: The problem is that you defined the `<<` overload an a `MainWind`, and the left-hand operand of this `<<` operator is not a `MainWind`. It is a `MainWind *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> //other.cpp
> MainWind *mainWind  = new MainWind;
> mainWind <<"str";
> ```

The reason is that `mainWind << "str"` looks for an `operator<<()` that accepts two arguments, the first of which is a `MainWind *`.

Whereas, you have defined a `MainWind::operator<<()` which is called with the first argument a `MainWind &`.     There is no direct conversion from a `MainWind *` to a `MainWind &` (or to a `MainWind`).    Hence the error message.

One way to get the code to compile is to change `mainWind <<"str"` to `*mainWind << "str"`.    The `*` dereferences the pointer, and produces a reference, which is what your `operator<<()` expects.

The catch is then that

```
*mainWind << "str" << "another str";
```

will not compile, since it is equivalent to

```
(*mainWind).operator<<("str") << "another str";
```

where `(*mainWind).operator<<("str")` returns a `MainWind *`.   This causes the same problem (again) when trying to stream `"another str"`.

The real fix is to change `operator<<()` so it returns a reference

```
//  within the class definition of MainWind

MainWind &operator<<(const QString &str);

// definition of the operator<<()

MainWind &MainWind::operator<<(const QString &str)
{
    ui->serverConsole->insertPlainText(str);
    return *this;
}
```

and change the calling code to either

```
//other.cpp version 2

MainWind *mainWind  = new MainWind;
*mainWind <<"str";

// this will work too

*mainWind << "str" << "another str";  

//   note reliance on cleaning up mainWind to avoid a memory leak

delete mainWind;
```

There is no other fix that would allow you to use `mainWind << "str"` since overloading non-member `operator<<()` is only permitted on class or enumerated types, not on pointers.

Comment: A lot of text makes little sense ... How do I overload the function as in addition to my question?

Comment: I would like to using the pointer without the "*". Therefore, I want to overload the function.

Comment: Your example of function overload still result error: MainWind *mW = new MainWind; mW << "str"; This is for your last insight? Maybe I do not use it correctly?

Comment: @vlad - yeah, okay.   I forgot that overloading of global `operator<<()` to accept pointer arguments (as the first argument) is not allowed.   Edited accordingly.   In short:  there is no solution to your requirement.

Comment: Compilation of the function code (with the first parameter as the pointer) is  success normal, it means an error of use ... But where? MainWind *mW = new MainWind; mW << "str"

Comment: The function may compile, however, there is no way it can be called  when doing `mW << "str"`.    If there is a member version of `MainWind::operator<<()` then `*mW << "str"` is implicitly translated to a call of something like`(*mW).MainWind::operator<<("str")`.    However, the standard specifies no equivalence which allows what you want i.e. turn `mW << "str"` into a call of any `MainWind::operator<<()`.  In short, you're trying to do something that the standard doesn't support/allow. The closest you can come is the (ugly)  `mW->operator<<("str")`  (i.e. do what you want the compiler to do).

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `*mainWind << QString("str");`. The LHS has to be an object, not a pointer.

While at it, I strongly recommend changing the `operator<<` function to return a reference to the object, not a pointer.

```
MainWind& operator<<(const QString &str);
```

and the implementation to

```
MainWind& MainWind::operator<<(const QString &str)
{
    ui->serverConsole->insertPlainText(str);
    return *this;
}
```

That will allow you to chain the operator.

```
*mainWind << QString("str") << QString("Second string");
```

Comment: This is fine, but I need to work with exactly the pointer, but the function overloading given above gives to me a result similar to the past.

Comment: @Vlad, using pointers instead of objects is a choice. I am sure it is not a requirement. Morever, using pointers with the `<<` operators is not idiomatic. Just something to think about.

Answer (score 3):

You overloaded `<<` on `MainWnd` not `MainWnd*`.

`*mainWind << QString("str");`

Also you want `QString const&`

Comment: And if I want to use the pointer yet? without the "*" at the beginning. Is it possible? How should I change the overload?

Comment: @Vlad, you can use `mainWind->operator<<(QString("str"));`

Comment: @Vlad, that's why you should use `*mainWind << ...`

Comment: @RSahu Could you look at the added to the question above, where it is indicated that the pointer is expected as first op.There is a function overload, not a method.

Comment: @Vlad, try making the second argument `QString const& str`.

Comment: @vlad ask another question using "ask question". Invalidating existing answers to valid questions is frowned upon.